# Losing connection to Firebase realtime database after leaving the app in the background for a while

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My app loses connection to Firebase Realtime Database after being put in the background for a while ... In other words when I reopen my app again after being in the background for a while, Realtime Database services stop functioning until I clear the app data at the phone settings and everything back to normal ... I read about similar cases and found out that Android destroys resources (Socket connection) with Firebase after being put in the background for a specific period of time. However, there was no straightforward solution provided to restore connection after going back to the app ... so any help ?

Comment: What is the API level of the device or emulator you are testing on?

Comment: API level is 24.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem using an API 24 emulator with a test app built using Firebase version 11.2.2.  I used `adb` commands to force changes in idle state ([Doze Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html)).  For the few tests I did, the websocket connection was always re-established upon exiting Doze mode.  If your app does not need to be connected when in the background, consider removing all listeners in `onStop()` methods and reattaching them in `onStart()`.  With that, Firebase will cleanly disconnect after a minute in background.And..

Comment: And will reconnect when the listeners are reattached when the app comes to the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

It is expected that apps will lose their socket connections when there is no visible activity.  That's the way the Firebase SDK works.  Also, Android will aggressively pause background applications so they don't consume data and battery when the user isn't actively using it.

When an activity becomes started again, the Firebase SDK should attempt to restore the websocket it uses to communicate with the server.  This websocket is fully managed by the SDK.  You don't have to do anything to tell it to reconnect.

Comment: Well apparently It doesn't reconnect ... all data listeners and writing attempts are not working.

Comment: It does, otherwise a lot of apps would be broken out there.  Turn on debug logging to get more information about what's going on.  `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBU‌​G)`